# Should try always be followed by catch?

Tags: java, try-catch

```
static void test() {
    try {
        System.out.print(x.toString() + " ");
    }
    finally { System.out.print("finally "); }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try 
    {
        test(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { System.out.print("exception "); 
}
```

The output is `finally exception`.

Why is there no error being thrown at compile time although `try` is not followed by `catch` in `test()`?

Comment: try-catch-finally is for runtime exceptions and not for compile time errors

Comment: @Kris, not true. Checked exceptions are **not** runtime exceptions and `try-catch-finally` is valid for any exceptions.

Comment: @TEG sorry, you are right, I just wanted to point out the usefulness of try-catch-finally to compile time errors, and I meant all type of errors/exceptions which happens when program runs rather then when its compiled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java versions before version 7 allow for these three combinations of try-catch-finally:

```
try - catch
try - catch - finally
try - finally
```

The exception is probably a `NullPointerException` since there's no `x` declared as a static field and initialized inline or in the `main` method. `finally` block will be always executed no matter of what's going on in the `try` or/and `catch` block.

Comment: Java 7 allows `try` by itself for ARM. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey first i was shocked to know that Java is used in ARM Architectures (RISC based) until i read your answer ;)

Comment: @Johnydep Java is also available for Linux on ARM ;)

Comment: @Johnydep There are optional ARM features to support execution of Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey somehow in intelliJ I can't use try alone in Java 8 :/

Answer (score 10):

Java 7 add ARM (Automatic Resource Management) will means you can use `try` alone.

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("out.txt")) {
    pw.println("Hello World!");
}
```

This closes `pw` when this scope exits.

Answer (score 3):

Because the only requirement is that the try block must be followed by at least one catch block ***or*** a finally block.

See: [The try statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#79311) in the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

Try doesn't necessarily need a catch clause.

The following are valid exception handling clauses in java:

- `try-catch` clause,
- `try-finally` clause or
- `try-catch-finally` clause.

Check the [JLS Chapter 11.3, Handling Exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html).

Answer (score 1):

try must be followed by a catch OR a finally block in java.

the catch is not necessary if a finally is there.

Answer (score 0):

`try` must either by followed by `catch` or `finally`. no need of `catch` block always. Without either of `catch` or `finally` compile time error will occur

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question really. There is no compile time error because a try block does not have to be followed by a catch. It's semantically correct, and often necessary to just want a finally block after a try.

Perhaps the exception is being thrown from the method but you still want to close a connection.

For example:

```
public void connect() throws IOException {
    Socket s = new Socket();
    try {
        s.getInputStream();         
    }
    finally {
        s.close();
    }
}
```